# VBA cell formatting of .summary

Tags: vba, excel

I have a piece of code that needs to have a different format. The main area of interest at the moment is the wording/format of the subject line in the email. Here is what I have so far.

```
    ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
    With .Parent.MailEnvelope
        .Introduction = "" 

       With .Item
            .to = "Somebodysemail@whatever.com;"
            .to = "Somebodysemail@whatever.com;"
            .CC = ";"
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = Date & " Completion " & summary.[B8] & "% """
            .send
            .display
        End With
```

My main subject line as of now when running the Macro is:

7/26/2018 completion 0.992%

and I want it to read:

7/26/2018 completion 99.2%

When calling upon the contents of cell B8, it is already in the format of 99.2 in my excel workbook. I do not understand why it is not copying the exact contents of the cell. Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a programming question so may have been better suited to a related site like SuperUser, but it's such a quick answer I might as well...

---

Replace this line in your code:

```
.Subject = Date & " Completion " & summary.[B8] & "% """
```

...with:

```
.Subject = Date & " Completion " & Format(summary.[B8],"0.0%")
```

---

To answer your question, you are correct in saying:

> *"cell B8, it is already in the **format** of 99.2"*

"Format" being the key word.  Numbers in Excel are stored as *just numbers*, and without formatting.  When you change the formatting of a cell, that's only changing the way that the number is displayed, **not** the actual number itself.  This is a good thing for several reasons.

I highly recommend taking the time do check out a tutorial such as [**this one**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/basic-tasks-in-excel-dc775dd1-fa52-430f-9c3c-d998d1735fca?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US). A little bit of time invested now will save a lot of time later.

Good luck!